# From Win 8 host machine can't access Oracle on VMWARE using WS 2008

Tags: oracle, vmware

I've just created a vmware virtual machine with Windows Server 2008 and intalled Oracle XE 11g.

On the host system (Windows 8.1), I am trying to connect to this Oracle Server through SQL Developer, without any success. The error I get is:

> Status: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

The network is set to **Host-only: A private network shared with the host**, and I can ping to it from the host machine.

Also I have already disabled the firewall in the VM.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what data you use to connect to your database? Hostname, SID, port, username? Can you also show the contents of the `path_to_oracle\network\admin\tnsnames.ora` file? I would also recommend to restart the machine and see if that helps (had the same issue). Also, can you log into your database from within the Virtual Machine using SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same problem, I was need to connect from host to vm oracle database, my solution below

- Use network bridge adapter om VM
- Set static IP address on VM
- Disable vm firewall or forward port (1521)
- Stop database instance, listener etc
- Edit ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora and
  RACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora to change **localhost** on
  **static ip**
- Start database